# UnityEngine - Multiple tags on Trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have a system, when enemy(Peter) is randomly walking. There are many triggers that are suppose to give command to Peter to start chase the Player if both are in the same trigger. But the trigger don't want to detect both tags at the same time.

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) 
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player") && other.CompareTag("Peter"))
        {
          PeterSystem.PlayerSpooted = true; // Chase player
        }
    }
```

Any idea please?

I tried it with booleans, but the chase was activated even that both were in different trigger. That means if there are 50 triggers with the same script, the booleans are connected to all scripts of same kind in a scene.

```
void Update()
    {
        if(PlayerIn && PeterIn && flashlight.FlashLightIsOn)
        {
            PeterSystem.PlayerSpooted = true;
            
        }    
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            PlayerIn = true;
        }
        if(other.tag == "Peter")
        {
            PeterIn = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) 
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            PlayerIn = false;
        }
        if(other.tag == "Peter")
        {
            PeterIn = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: well you will never satisfy `f(other.CompareTag("Player") && other.CompareTag("Peter"))` as you can only have 1 tag on an object.  now theres  a whole ton of ways you could do it.  What works for you and your game is really up to you, but you could keep a list of things inside the trigger.   You could make an event and have peter listen to the event which is triggered if the player enters.. you can use a sphere cast to see if both are in range..

Comment: Should this maybe be an **or** check? `if(other.CompareTag("Player") || other.CompareTag("Peter"))` .... `the booleans are connected to all scripts of same kind in a scene.` are they `static`?

Answer (score 0):

With the code below you can keep a list of all GameObjects inside of a trigger area. You can use the "contains" method on the list to check if specific objects are present.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggerZoneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<GameObject> objectsInside = new List<GameObject>();

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (!objectsInside.Contains(other.gameObject))
        {
            objectsInside.Add(other.gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (objectsInside.Contains(other.gameObject))
        {
            objectsInside.Remove(other.gameObject);
        }
    }

    // Optional: You can add a method to retrieve the list of objects inside the trigger.
    public List<GameObject> GetObjectsInside()
    {
        return objectsInside;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by this script:

```
 {
    if(flashlight.FlashLightIsOn && PlayerTriggerName == PeterTriggerName)
    {
        PeterSystem.PlayerSpooted = true;
        
    }    
}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if(other.tag == "Player")
    {
        PlayerTriggerName = gameObject.name;
    }
    if(other.tag == "Peter")
    {
         PeterTriggerName = gameObject.name;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) 
{
     if(other.tag == "Player")
    {
        PlayerTriggerName = " ";
        
    }
    if(other.tag == "Peter")
    {
         PeterTriggerName = "";
         
    }
}
```

Anyway thank you all for answers! :)